# Sort documents in firestore collection chronologically

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to sort documents in collection chronologically when they are created? Currently, they are all over the place. For example, in To-Do app, when you add new item to collection, it should display at the bottom, last, not somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DateTime.now()` for the document ID. This should put the collection in chronological order.

For example:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Posts').document(DateTime.now().toString()).setData({});
```

Comment: Also I should note that Doug Stevenson's answer is also an ideal solution. This is especially true if your app is having users with different time zones since my solution would not order correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define an order based on some data in the document, and order your queries based on that field.

The typical solution for time-base order to make sure your documents all contain a timestamp field that you can use to sort them.  When you call [add()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/add.html) (or other methods to update data), you can tell Firestore to use the current time using [FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html):

```
collection(...).add({
    ...,  // your other fields
    createdOn: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

Then you can use that field to sort when querying with [orderBy()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/orderBy.html):

```
collection(...).orderBy('createdOn')
```